Как читать изображения из PDF с помощью Poppler c++?
Я использую poppler версии 24.3.0 и вопрос такой: как считать слой изображений со страницы PDF-ки простым способом также, как считать текстовый слой, типа:
poppler::page* page = doc->create_page(page_id);
page->text();

Или такого способа нет? Как вообще считывать изображения с PDF?

Переведите вопрос на русский язык
